# Having Trouble converting list to integers and Iterating through the list

Tags: python, function, loops, integer

I'm struggling to figure out how to convert a list into integers, and iterating a function over each of those elements. I want the function to check each element, and need each element in the list to be converted to integers.

```
years = ["25", "1955", "2000", "1581", "1321", "1285", "4365", "4", "1432", "3423", "9570"]
def isLeap():
    year = list(map(int, years))
    if year in years >= 1583:
        print(year, "Is a Gregorian Calendar Year.")
    elif year in years < 1583:
        print(year, "Is not a Gregorian Calendar Year.")
    elif year in years % 400 == 0 or year in years % 4 == 0:
        print(year, "Is a Leap Year.")
    elif year in years % 400 == 1 or year in years % 4 == 1:
        print(year, "Is NOT a Leap Year.")
    else:
        print("Test cannot be performed.")
for i in years:
    isLeap()
```

Comment: `if year in years >= 1583:` what do you expect this is supposed to be doing? Seems like a mashup of `for` and `if`

Comment: You already converted it to a list of `int`s, right here: `year = list(map(int, years))` to iterate over that list just do `for x in year: ...`

Answer (score 0):

Converting list of strings to list of ints can be simply done with list comprehension:

`int_list = [int(year) for year in years]`

Another visible problem in your code would be understanding scope of variables and passing args to function.

If you iterate over years then pass the year item to your function and use in scope of the function

```
def isLeap(year):
...

for int_year in int_list:
    isLeap(int_year)
```

Answer (score 0):

Given what you are trying to do, I believe this is one way to do it, combining a `for` loop for elements you pass to the function (in list format), with the `if-elif-else` conditions you stated.

```
years = ["25", "1955", "2000", "1581", "1321", "1285", "4365", "4", "1432", "3423", "9570"]
def isLeap(years):
    for i in years:
        if int(i) >= 1583:
            print(i, "Is a Gregorian Calendar Year.")
        elif int(i) < 1583:
            print(i, "Is not a Gregorian Calendar Year.")
        elif int(i) % 400 == 0 or int(years[i]) % 4 == 0:
            print(i, "Is a Leap Year.")
        elif int(i) % 400 == 1 or int(years[i]) % 4 == 1:
            print(i, "Is NOT a Leap Year.")
        else:
            print("Test cannot be performed.")
isLeap(years)
```

Output:

```
25 Is not a Gregorian Calendar Year.
1955 Is a Gregorian Calendar Year.
2000 Is a Gregorian Calendar Year.
1581 Is not a Gregorian Calendar Year.
1321 Is not a Gregorian Calendar Year.
1285 Is not a Gregorian Calendar Year.
4365 Is a Gregorian Calendar Year.
4 Is not a Gregorian Calendar Year.
1432 Is not a Gregorian Calendar Year.
3423 Is a Gregorian Calendar Year.
9570 Is a Gregorian Calendar Year.
```

Comment: don't loop over indices, loop directly over the list itself...

Comment: Thanks I was focused on something else and mistaked it.

Answer (score 0):

You should do your conversion from string to int outside of your `isLeap` function:

`for year in map(int, years):`

Your function should accept a year parameter:

`def isLeap(year)`

And your test should simply be: `if year >= 1583 # etc.`

However, there is also a logic issue here: because you're using `if/elif`, you will never determine whether something is a leap year, because one of your first two if statements will always be correct. (It's either >= 1583, or it's < 1583; no other conditions will ever be checked.)